# Python printing only when variable changes

Tags: python, printing, interface, command-line-interface

I'm working on a small project that involves a command line interface. I'd like to be able to print a row of characters as long as the command line. I'm able get the dimensions with

```
width, height = get_terminal_size()
```

If i'm trying to print a block character as long as the width of the terminal, I can do this with the following:

```
import os
block = unichr(0x2588)
while True:
    os.system('cls')
    print block*width
```

however, this looks choppy, as it is drawing and redrawing the row each time. I'm trying to find a way to only draw it when the width changes, but i'm struggling to do so. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Typically your loop would look something like: while 1 { cls; print foo; flush output; sleep 1}. That should be enough to fix the issue you are seeing.

Comment: @Claris i'm not sure what you mean

Comment: You need a sleep statement. Also as an alternative to cls you can do something like: print "\rfoo",

Comment: @Claris You need `from __future__ import braces` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Just check whether the width has changed.

```
while True:
    os.system('cls')
    if width!=last_width:
        print block*width
        last_width = width
```